# Why is this custom reverse function acting strange?

Tags: python

I needed to write a custom reverse function, here is the code:

```
def reverse(x):
    length = len(x)
    out = x
    for i in range(length):
        out[length-i-1] = x[i]
    return out

print(reverse([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]))
```

but for some reason this outputs `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`, does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Stopping halfway only turns the input list into a palindrome.

Comment: Use `out = x[:]` to make a copy of `x`

Comment: `a[::-1]` will reverse your list

Comment: simplify x[::-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`out = x` makes the variable `out` point to the same list as `x`. You probably want to do `out = x.copy()`.

Answer (score 2):

`out = x` doesn't make a copy: it just makes the name `out` refer to the same list as the name `x`.

While you can make a copy with something like `out = x.copy()` or `out = list(x)`, there's little reason to do so because you'll simply be overwriting every element of the resulting copy. Instead, just build a new list:

```
def reverse(x):
    length = len(x)
    out = []
    for i in range(length):
        out.append(x[length-i-1])
    return out
```

There are other, simpler and/or faster ways to produce a reversed list (list comprehensions, slicing, using the `reversed` type, etc) but I'll let you experiment with them on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Because you set out = x. And in python this is reference typed.

So in your loop, when you do out[0] = x[10], it sets out[0] to x[10], but it also sets x[0] to x[10] as x and out have the same reference.

If you want to create a reverse function from scratch, here is one of the best practices:

```
def reverse(my_list):
    i = 0             # first item
    j = len(my_list)-1   # last item
    while i<j:
        my_list[i], my_list[j] = my_list[j], my_list[i]
        i += 1
        j -= 1
    return my_list
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i just set out to a list that is 'length' long full of 0s and it worked

Comment: Don't name variables `list`, it shadows the inbuilt class `list`

Comment: yes you are right sorry for that

Answer (score -1):

```
def reverse(x):
    length = len(x)
    out = []
    for i in range(1,length+1):
        out.append(x[-i])
    
    return out
```

Comment: Since the question is "why is this happening", simply posting code does not *really* answer the question. Please add an explanation of *why* the original code did not work, how this code is different from the OP's code, and *why* it solves the problem.